# Python logger not show Warnings from external modules

Tags: python, logging

I am trying  to adapt the code from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html. I'm expecting all `INFO` messages (as well as anything of higher importance) to be displayed in the terminal, and all `DEBUG` messages (and anything higher) to be written to file.

Here is my logging setup:

In `main.py`:

```
import logging
import mymodule

def get_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")
    logger.propagate = False
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('out.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s -- %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    return logger

logger = get_logger()
# Do stuff...
```

In `mymodule.py`:

```
import logging
import other_modules

module_logger = logging.getLogger("main.functions")
# Other functions...
```

Warnings that get trigger by `other_modules` (which are not written by me) aren't getting logged, but are printed to the terminal. What's wrong with my setup?

p.s. I'm using a function to get `logger` so that I can hide it in some other file and make `main.py` more user friendly. I don't think this should have negative side effects?

Comment: Were you trying to implement the *pattern* from the [Logging from multiple modules HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules)?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I made a toy example similar to yours and everything gets logged to the console/shell but only `main.py` logs are written to the file. Is there a reason you are using a function for logging/logger configuration? I don't think you have given enough information as we don't know *which* logger `other_modules` is/are using. Even `mymodule` and `main` are using a different loggers.

Comment: I was trying to adapt the code from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html. I'm expecting all `INFO` messages (as well as anything of higher importnce) to be displayed in the terminal, and all `DEBUG` messages (and anything higher) to be written to file. I'm using a function to get `logger` so that I can hide it in some other file and make the `main.py` more user friendly.

Comment: You should add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet figured out why your solution isn't working - I'll add to this later.

To separate the logging configuration from the rest of your code put it in a separate module and import that module into the *top level* module.  Everything downstream will *inherit* through propagation unless specifically configured not to.

It looks like you want the same basic configuration for all logging so you only need to define the configuration of the root logger. In the following example the root logger's name is `''`.

**log_config.py**

```
import logging, logging.config

config = {'version':1,
          'handlers':{'fyle':{'class' : 'logging.FileHandler',
                              'level' : 'DEBUG',
                              'formatter' : 'primary',
                              'filename' : 'out.log'
                              },
                      'console':{'class' : 'logging.StreamHandler',
                                 'level' : 'INFO',
                                 'formatter' : 'primary',
                                 }
                      },
          'formatters':
          {'primary':{
              'format':'%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(name)s -- %(levelname)s - %(message)s'}
           },
          'loggers': {
              '': {'handlers':['console', 'fyle'],
                       'level':'DEBUG',
                       }
              }
          }

logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

[Logging HOWTO Advanced:Configuring Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)

---

**main.py**

```
import logging
import log_config
import foo

logger = logging.getLogger('main')
time.sleep(3)
logger.warning('This is tmp')
```

**foo.py**

```
import logging
import time
import bar    # other_modules

module_logger = logging.getLogger("main.functions")
module_logger.propagate = True
time.sleep(1)
module_logger.warning('This is foo!')
module_logger.debug('This is foo! debug')
```

**bar.py** (from *those other people*)

```
import logging
import time

time.sleep(2)
logging.warning('This is bar!!')
logging.debug('this is bar DEBUG')
```

---